# Jquery delete function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make Jquery delete function, here is the code, that I wrote -

```
$("a.delete").click(function(){         
        var target = $(this).attr("id");            
        var c = confirm('Do you really want to delete this category?');
        if(c==true) {
    $(target+"ul").delay(3000).fadeOut(200);
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
    });
```

Okay now to problem, when I press, button a with class delete, it correctly, shows up the dialog (and the id is correct), but after I press yes, it will delete it with php, without jquery fadeOut effect. 
My php code -

```
  public function deleteCategory() {
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'delete') {
      $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
      $sql = "DELETE FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = '".$id."'";
      mysql_query($sql);
    }
  }
```

Not sure where is the problem but I think it's inside $(target+"ul"), since I'm not sure, if it will add the target value and ul together.

In additional, how can I prevent the delete, if I press no? Currently, if I press no, it will still delete the category.

If you need any other information - ask.

Full code -

```
  public function showCategories() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && isset($_SESSION['user_level']) && $_SESSION['user_level'] == 'admin') {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `categories`";
      $q = mysql_query($sql);
      if(mysql_num_rows($q) > 0) {
        ?>
          <div class="recentorders" style="display: none;" id="categoryBox">
            <h5 class="colr">Categories</h5>
              <div class="account_table" style="width: 688px;">
                  <ul class="headtable" style="width: 680px;">
                      <li class="order">ID</li>
                      <li class="action" style="width: 430px;">Category Name</li>
                      <li class="action nobordr">Options</li>
                  </ul>
        <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
          ?>
            <ul class="contable" style="width: 680px;" id="cat<?php echo $row['id']; ?>ul">
                <li class="order"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></li>
                <li class="action" style="width: 430px;"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></li>
                <li class="action nobordr"><a href="?action=edit&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>#" class="first">Edit</a><a class="delete" id="cat<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" href="?action=delete&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>#">Delete</a></li>
            </ul>          
          <?php 
        }
        ?>
              </div>
          </div>
        <?php
      }
      else {
        // No categories created, please create one first.
      }
    }
    else {
      header('location: account.php');
    }
  }

  public function deleteCategory() {
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'delete') {
      $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
      $sql = "DELETE FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = '".$id."'";
      mysql_query($sql);
    }
  }
```

Comment: How you send to server information about category to delete?

Comment: Give us a sample of the HTML, it's hard to tell why the selector might not be correct. There are several approaches you could use, like $('#' + target + ' ul') OR $('ul',this). Without the HTML I don't know if you're looking for a UL inside of the container or if you have an different element with an ID of the target and "UL" after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're searching by ID you need to prefix your selector with a "#":

100% working sample on jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/E7QfY/

Change

```
 $(target+"ul").delay(3000).fadeOut(200);
```

to

```
 $('#' + target+"ul").delay(3000).fadeOut(200);
```

OR

```
 $(this).closest('ul').delay(3000).fadeOut(200);
```

I would also modify the code to this:

```
 $("a.delete").click(function(event){           
      if(confirm('Do you really want to delete this category?') == true){               
           $(this).closest('ul').delay(3000).fadeOut(200);
           window.location.href = $(this).attr('href'); //OR use AJAX and do an event.preventDefault();
      }
      else
           event.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: I've added a jsFiddle sample to the comment as proof that the selector change does work: http://jsfiddle.net/E7QfY/

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using an anchor tag that is causing a postback to the server which makes your page refresh before you see the animation. Make sure your anchor tag has an href defined as "#" to stop the postback from happening.

Comment: A better approach is to return false; or pass an event in to the click handeler and do event.preventDefault();

Comment: Hmm, with hash, I fixed the problem with cancel, but the fadeOut problem still persists.

Comment: It is likely that your selector is incorrect. Give us the HTML sample so we can see what you're trying to select. Remember, if you're looking by ID prefix your selector with "#".

Comment: Hello, I added the whole code, for this function, see first post (the jquery code is on top, and the php/html code is under it).

Answer (score 0):

You should use something else than A tag e.g. span or div. And then after clicking this element make your fadeout and after it redirect to the PHP script that deletes your object:

```
$("SPAN,DIV.delete").click(function(){         
    var target = $(this).attr("id");            
    var c = confirm('Do you really want to delete this category?');
    if(c==true) {
        $(target+"ul").delay(3000).fadeOut(200);
        window.location.href = URL TO PHP FILE
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
 });
```

Comment: whats the point of fading it out if you're going to redirect the user to the delete page?

Comment: I have no idea what is the point :) ask user1184908. He probably wants to give user some time to make a coffee. :)

Comment: Well, basically I need it to look "Attractive", with simple redirect, it wouldn't be the same ;)! I want it to look cool :), and so the users, wouldn't have to wait for page refresh, but instead have a fadeout effect.

Comment: Were you looking to use AJAX to send the delete request so the page doesnt have to refresh?

Comment: Well, yes, my idea was something similar. I won't make something like that without ajax?

Comment: Without AJAX user will simply wait longer. First until your effects finish, then until PHP does its job.

Comment: Okay I got it, gonna try to find one of ajax scripts ;)! By the way, I got classes, and in one of my classes I got delete function, how should I send ajax request then?